# Take jquery variable to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code:

```
// timer code
    var count=120;
    var pars = 0;
    var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); // will  run it every 1 second
    var redirect="index.php";

    function timer(){
      if (count <= 0){
         window.location = redirect;
      } else{
          if(pars == 1){

          } else {
            count=count-1;
          }
      }
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=":" + count ;
    }
```

which displays a timer in div#timer, and I need it to have a pause on some link click as follow:

```
$(".quad").click(function(){
    pars = 1;
});
```

As I am new to javascript, I think this problem is cause by global & private variables.
Can you help me please?

Comment: You may want to look at using the JQuery widget factory, which manages a lot of this for you, as in http://jqueryui.com/widget/ and http://onallthingsweb.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/building-jquery-widgets-part-1/

Comment: what's the actual problem that you are having? do you get an error (if so, what?), or is it just not working as you expect (what *is* it doing)?

Comment: The timer function is not pausing even if variable pars is not equal to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me. Make sure your .click event is registered after the document is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(
    $(".quad").click(function(){
        pars = 1;
    });
});
```

You should also do the redirect using

```
window.location.href = redirect;
```

Comment: The onload event is the key :)

Comment: Thanks dude, that gave me the solution :)

Comment: Ribot - Dude! You're website's a trip!!

Answer (score 1):

It's running OK [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EfVtR/2), too. This assumes the onload function refered to by others.

It's nicer to use:

```
      if(pars != 1){
        count=count-1;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both code snippets are working in the same scope. If you have your click handler code inside of a `document.ready` callback, move the timer code to the callback too.